# RESTKit Managed Object in a not Managed object as relationship

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a simple object mapping and as a relationship I've added two managed object mappings.
I am receiving the following error:
`CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Error'`

Without adding the relationship the setup works for RestKit. I've also found some other topics about this error message here on the site, but the route is correct and the `persistencoordinator` is present so I have no other clue why it isn't working.

---

Edit:
Here are my mappings:

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MyManagedObject" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"property1", @"property2"]];

RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyObjectForRequest class]];
[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"someProperty1", @"someProperty2"]];
[objectMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"EntityProperty" mapping:entityMapping];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping pathPattern:@"SomeLink" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

And now the call:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:objectForRequest method:RKRequestMethodPOST @"SomeLink" parameters:nil];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        // Do something
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Handle error
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: Please show how you're defining your mappings and calling RestKit to do the download. Are you instantiating any managed objects yourself?

Comment: No, I am not instantiating. The error comes when the RestKit tries to parse the response.

Comment: Are you setting the managed object store of the RKObjectManager?

Comment: Yes, I am, and it isn'nt nil, I've tried it out

Comment: Why part in core data and part out? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Because I wouldn't like to store all the parts, but they are also important when I receive it from the server. And one more reason is that this is how I receive from the server. So, I don't really have another choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either be using 2 `RKObjectMapping`s or 2 `RKEntityMapping`s, you can't really mix and match. It could potentially work if the root item was the managed object but the way you have it is a little strange.

Comment: Ok, I am going to check this out.

Comment: Ok, it works, I've created a not managed object, added as mapping then in the success block I've created the managed objects manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your object manager to use managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:fail rather than objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:fail, that'll initialize your core data entity properly through the managedObjectContext.

I'm using it right now because I have a normal NSObject as a response class with a member variable named "value" that contains a core data entity.